# GraphQL with NestJS InputType class-validator

Tags: graphql, nestjs

On a new project using GraphQL for the first time I´m struggling with the NestJS class-validator.

**Expected Behavior / Issue description:**

I would like to use the class with @InputType decorator directly as validator. This should be the single source of truth regarding Input arguments.

If I enable the Validator globally, as shown below, it strips out each value described on the corresponding class.

Also If I enable forbidNonWhitelist it also states that those properties should not exist on this query params.

This applies for queries aswell as for Mutations.

**Code for reference:**

**InputType with class:**

```js
@InputType()
export class CreateUserArgs {
    @Field()
    firstName: string
    @Field({nullable: true})
    lastName?: string
}
```

**Minimal Resolver snippet:**

```js
@Mutation(returns => User)
  async userTest (
    @Args('createUserArgs') createUserArgs: CreateUserArgs
  ) {
    console.log(createUserArgs) // resolves to empty object
    return {
      firstName: createUserArgs.firstName,
      lastName: createUserArgs.lastName
    }
  }
```

**enabled validation pipe globally on main.ts**

```js
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    whitelist: true,
    transform: true
  }))
```